# Super complicated SQL statement...maybe impossible

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I've done some programming and some SQL but is no developer except for my own little projects.
I now have a problem I would love to solve in pure SQL but can't really figure out how.
I have 2 simple tables that i need to draw a monthly report from, but i need to do some counting and that's the tricky part.
Here are the structure...

```
table 
  km_locations
columns
  location_id INT
  location_name TXT

table
  km_trips
colums
  trip_id INT
  trip_date DATE
  start_location_id INT
  end_location_id INT
  km_start INT
  km_end INT
```

And here are the rules that make it too complicated for me to figure out...

1. Create a report within a specific date range eg. between
   2016-02-15 and 2016-03-15.
2. Replace start_location_id and end_location_id with corresponding
   location_name in km_locations.
3. Count how many similar trips i made within the last 12 months and
   show the incremental value in a separate column.
4. Only count trips too or from Home, and only count if no other trips with same start and end destination combo have been made on the date.

The sample below without total_trips I can get with this statement.

```
SELECT
t.trip_date,
c1.location_name AS 'trip_start',
c2.location_name AS 'trip_end',
t.km_start,
t.km_end
FROM km_trips t
LEFT JOIN km_locations c1 ON c1.location_id = t.start_location_id
LEFT JOIN km_locations c2 ON c2.location_id = t.end_location_id
WHERE t.trip_date BETWEEN '2016-02-06' AND '2016-03-10'
ORDER BY t.trip_date ASC, t.km_start ASC
```

wanted sample date output

```
id     date     trip_start      trip_end        km_start    km_end  total_trips
1   2016-02-15  Home            Grocery Store   10675       10681   8
2   2016-02-15  Grocery Store   Gas Station     10681       10684
3   2016-02-15  Gas Station     Home            10684       10689   5
4   2016-02-16  Home            Grocery Store   10689       10695   9
5   2016-02-16  Grocery Store   Home            10695       10701
6   2016-02-17  Home            School          10701       10723   12
7   2016-02-17  School          Grocery Store   10723       10739
8   2016-02-17  Grocery Store   Friends House   10739       10755
9   2016-02-17  Friends House   Home            10755       10767   7
10  2016-02-18  Home            Friends House   10767       10783   8
11  2016-02-18  Friends House   Home            10755       10767
12  2016-02-19  Home            Friends House   10767       10783   9
13  2016-02-19  Friends House   Grocery Store   10783       10792
14  2016-02-19  Grocery Store   Home            10792       10798   10
```

It might be too much for a SQL statement but I'm thinking that it might be possible with views, unions and som mad skills.
It is a new project I am moving from Excel, so I'm open to any suggestions to table structures that can make this work.
Right now I'm trying to make this work with SQLite but will go with another databse if that is my only option.

Thanks.

Comment: The start and end values will only make sense on a per-trip basis. What does the total have to do with each trip?

Comment: The total should be how many times i made a trip with home as either start or end destination within the last 12 months. Made some formatting error so the specifics are 'hidden' in rule no. 4.

Comment: If you can express what that means in SQL you'll be one step closer to solving this problem. You may need to make a derivative table with the trip counts you can `JOIN` in.

Comment: Mysql and sqlite are very different systems. Remove irrelevant tag

Comment: That is my problem in a nutshell, I can create the statement that get the data whithout the incremented trip counter, but don't know where to start when to get the total_trips data.

Comment: I think both are relevant. If someone can help me with what I'm trying to do in either system I'm happy.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Please provide the `.dump` output of your test database so that other people do not have to enter data by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Try correlated subquery kind of

```
SELECT
t.trip_date,
c1.location_name AS 'trip_start',
c2.location_name AS 'trip_end',
t.km_start,
t.km_end,
(SELECT count(DISTINCT t2.trip_date) cnt
 FROM km_trips t2
 WHERE t2.trip_date < t.trip_date
    AND  t2.start_location_id = t.start_location_id
    AND  t2.end_location_id = t.end_location_id
    AND (SELECT location_id FROM km_locations WHERE location_name = 'home') 
         IN (t2.start_location_id, t2.end_location_id)
 ) count
FROM km_trips t
LEFT JOIN km_locations c1 ON c1.location_id = t.start_location_id
LEFT JOIN km_locations c2 ON c2.location_id = t.end_location_id
WHERE t.trip_date BETWEEN '2016-02-06' AND '2016-03-10'
ORDER BY t.trip_date ASC, t.km_start ASC
```

Comment: Thank you very much, will do.

Comment: Thank you Serg, that was very fast and a lot closer to the solution then I was able to get. I've tested and there are 2 problems.

Comment: Thank you Serg, that was very fast and a lot closer to the solution then I was able to get. I've tested and there are 2 problems. First the count start with zero so it basically starts counting from the second start end combo. Tried just adding one but couldn't wihtout adding it to those not including home, it is a small issue I can work around. The bigger problem is that similar start end combos should count as one eg. home->Grocery and Grocery->Home shoud count toward the same total. The other big issue is that eg. Grocery can only count once towards the total each day.